Ubuntu 22.04 boot issue on Mac Pro 5,1. Cannot read /EFI/
I have attempted posting this question on the official Ubuntu forum/Discourse but I do not have access rights to post – maybe because my account is too new.
I have a Mac Pro 5,1 running OCLP (OpenCore Legacy Patcher) that can select to boot any one of three internal SSDs. The SSDs contain : Ventura, Sonoma and Ubuntu 22.04 (?). The 4th SSD contains a Windows 10 Virtual machine. Until a couple of days ago I could easily boot any of the two MAC OS or Ubuntu Linux. Because of a very slow start-up issue, I had to revert OCLP 2.1.2 to 2.0.2 which fixed the slow start-up. I can no longer boot the Ubuntu system.
Now I know the immediate response will be "What did you change? OCLP? Well it must be an OCLP issue. Ask for support on that forum". I did post the following there and received a response that my machine's symptoms indicated this is a Linux problem. It may well be, but I didn't change anything on that disk, however I will post the issue below in the hope someone can get my Ubuntu system bootable again.
The setup was that when the Ubuntu Linux SSD was selected to boot from OCLP boot picker, then GRUB2 loaded which gave me control over which Linux kernel was loaded (to deal with another issue).
The error messages I now get when I select the Ubuntu Linux 22.04 SSD from the OCLP boot picker are
Could not read /EFI/ : Invalid parameter
Error: could not find boot options: Invalid parameters
start_image() returned Invalid Parameter
OC: Boot failed – Invalid parameter
OCB: StartImage failed – Invalid Parameter

So I think my system has an invalid parameter.
Is there something I can edit that will make my Linux system bootable?
The Ubuntu ext4(?) drive is not mountable on the macOS system. There is some code that makes the ext4 drive mountable on macOS, but only in read mode – and if I need to edit something on the Ubuntu drive I can’t do that from MAC OS. If I remove the Ubuntu drive from the Mac Pro, place it in a USB caddy and attach that drive to a Windows machine will I be able to read and edit the contents of the drive – if that is what is needed to fix the boot problem?
Further info
I removed the Ubuntu boot drive from the Mac Pro tray and placed it inside a USB caddy.  I was able to boot the Ubuntu system with the USB caddy plugged into a (Lenovo i5) desktop PC. I was able to logon to the system and all apps seemed to work fine.
I plugged the USB caddy containing the Ubuntu drive into the front of the Mac Pro and OCLP recognized the drive showing it as a yellow rectangle with the label "No Name", however when that drive was selected for boot on the Mac Pro the /EFI/ error messages documented above occurred.
I have found the following page: https://unixhint.com/failed-to-open-efi-ubuntu-invalid-parameter/
Even though the Ubuntu drive boots correctly on a PC I will try out the recommendations on that site to see if I can make the drive bootable on the Mac Pro running OCLP 2.0.2.
Update 2
I have found an Ubuntu utility called boot-repair that attempt to diagnose any boot issues and repair them. the diagnosis ran fine but the repair process failed. I have posted that issue on the new Ubuntu Discorse server as my new account now has rights to posts support questions. See: link to Ubuntu Discorse post

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.   Being off-topic (ie. me talking about discourse...); you can (with a new account) ask questions on the Ubuntu Discourse if in the correct Forums/Support area; go thru https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/welcome-to-support-and-help/49951 but you will be stopped from posting in non-support areas (with a new account).  You're welcome to keep your question here though instead.

@guiverc Thanks. I'm sure I went to the support area on Discourse and categorised the query as "other" and was blocked with "insufficient access rights" or "insufficient authority" or something similar. I'm happy to leave the question here if I get some suggestions as what to try to fix the problem. From symptoms, even though I didn't change Ubuntu disk, do you think the problem lies in Ubuntu boot process?

@guiverc (Continuing the off-topic discussion about posting to Discourse)The error message I get when trying to post to https://discourse.ubuntu.com/c/support-and-help is "An error occurred: Access Denied"

Back on topic.I removed the Ubuntu boot drive from the Mac Pro tray and placed it inside a USB caddy.  I was able to boot the Ubuntu system with the USB caddy plugged into a (Lenovo i5) desktop PC. I was able to logon to the system and all apps seemed to work fine.
I plugged the USB caddy containing the Ubuntu drive into the front of the Mac Pro and OCLP recognized the drive showing it as a yellow rectangle with the label “No Name”. However, when that drive was selected for boot on the Mac Pro the /EFI/ error messages documented above occurred.
......

.....  I have found the following page: https://unixhint.com/failed-to-open-efi-ubuntu-invalid-parameter/
So even though the Ubuntu drive boots correctly on a PC I will try out the recommendations on that site to see if I can make the drive bootable on the MacPro running OCLP 2.0.2.

Personally I think, for whatever reason, having to revert to OCLP 2.0.2 to solve a different problem - has caused some problem in the way OCLP "calls" the Linux boot loader. However, I know nothing of how these things work and rely on others for support. Thanks
